# How do I get ruby gem 'slop' to return an array of filenames after a shell glob

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to get the ruby gem 'slop' to accept a list of files that are being provided through a shell glob.  Thus in a directory where I have files foo_1, foo_2, foo_3, I want to pass my_prog -f foo* and have the option array contain the three file names as three separate elements.

```
require 'slop'

opts = Slop.parse do |o|
  o.array '-f', '--files', 'List of files', delimiter: ' '
end

files = opts[:files]

puts "Files to process: #{files}"

myprog.rb -f foo_*  ==>  Files to process: ["foo_1"]
```

Is there a way to do this?  I'd prefer not to switch away from Slop, and I have been using it for other arguments happily enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, after the slop processing is done, remaining arguments on the command line are available in opts.arguments.  So one approach is to drop the '-f' parameter and have the arguments that remain in opts.arguments be the list of files.  It's a pretty reasonable way to go in terms of specifying a user interface.  Lots of unix commands work this way. (Just listing files to be processed at the end of the command.)  ls and grep being two examples.

Answer (score 0):

so when you pass arguments into a ruby script they get parsed into `ARGV` as an array.

```bash
# myprog.rb -f foo_*

ARGV # => ["-f", "foo_1", "foo_2", "foo_3"]
```

`slop` parser does not understand that `foo_2` and `foo_3` are a part of `-f` flag and they get ingnored

although, `slop` parser will consume this `["-f", "foo_1 foo_2 foo_3"]` *(but that's not how `ARGV` is constructed)*

**the only solution here I see is to rewrite their parser**